# Cloudron Open Port 5080

Tags: linux, ubuntu, firewall

I'm attempting to run Antemedia on a Server which is pre-installed with Cloudron. It appears Cloudron's Firewall system has blocked port 5080 by default. There doesn't appear to be an option to open this port inside Cloudron. Does anyone have an idea how I can open port 5080 so I can access the Antmedia Application as this runs on port 5080?

Comment: What did Cloudron support say when you contacted them?

Comment: @MichaelHampton i bet NOTHING due the fact, he did wrote here instead there :)